# How to export one developer account when there are multiple developer accounts in a xcode profile

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-app-store

I have a Mac which has multiple developer accounts. Out of which I want to export one developer account to another mac. When I try it all the developer accounts are getting exported to the profile. Also tried deleting other developer accounts. Still those gets exported. Pls suggest how can this be done.

Comment: check this . http://stackoverflow.com/a/35454724/4910767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select particular certificate for that developer account from Keychain Access and export .p12 file and install it in other mac to use that account in other mac.